# IE Automation - Click does not work

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, click

I am trying to automate clicking a button in IE without any success. Any help would be appreciated. The web page is a public search site: https://eams.dwc.ca.gov/WebEnhancement/

There are a fews required input text boxes and three buttons on that page. The buttons are: Cancel, Reset and Next.

My code to populate the fields and clicking the Next button:

```
oIE = CREATEOBJECT([InternetExplorer.Application])
oIE.Navigate([https://eams.dwc.ca.gov/WebEnhancement/])
oie.visible = .t.

oie.document.forms[0].elements[0].value='somebodys first name'
oie.document.forms[0].elements[1].value='somebodys last name'
oie.document.forms[0].elements[3].value='some email'
oie.document.forms[0].elements[4].selectedindex = 2

?oie.document.forms[0].elements[7].value && displays Next
oie.document.forms[0].elements[7].click  && does not work
oie.document.forms[0].submit && does not work

inputCollection = oie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
?inputcollection.item[6].value  && displays Next
inputcollection.item[6].click() && does not work.
```

View Source contains this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<p align ="center" class="pageTitleLayout" >Requestor information capture</p>
<form id="requestor" action="InformationCapture" method="post">
<table align='center'>
...
...
<tr>
    <th>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel" > 
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Reset" > 
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next" >
    </th>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The following code is equivalent to clicking the Next button:
    oIE.Document.forms[0].submit(3)
The solution was passing 3 as a parameter to the Submit method.